# I have a large data frame which I want to write into a table while reducing the processing time

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, dataframe, multiprocessing

Here is my attempt below:

```py
def insert():
    mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products(id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(255), sku VARCHAR(255), description TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (id, sku))")
    for i,row in df.iterrows():
        sql = "INSERT INTO  products (name, sku, description) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"
        mycursor.execute(sql, tuple(row))
        mydb.commit()
                        
num_processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
chunk_size = int(df.shape[0]/num_processes)
print(chunk_size)
chunks = np.array_split(df, chunk_size)
print(chunks)
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_processes)

result = pool.map(insert, chunks)
print(result)
```

For some reason, the code doesn't execute after `chunks = np.array_split(df, chunk_size)` and it's stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Oh no;  single transactions and `multiprocessing` :'(

Comment: I haven't tried with MySQL but have you seen [`df.to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)?

Comment: Basically, you want to limit the number of transactions to the db. Get rid of `multiprocessing` for a start, and then see whether you can use `to_sql` or some way to use `executemany`

Comment: @roganjosh even if i use executemany the processing time remains the same. the dataframe contains 500000 rows. so only option left is to split the df and process it simultaneously

Comment: It will only remain the same if you keep the `for` loop

Comment: I think I invented MySQL in my head from `mycursor`. What is the db?

Comment: yes its mysql only